# overloading operator<< undefined reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

This is my h file:

```
class Student
{
public:
    Student(std::string _name, size_t _age)
    :m_name(_name), m_age(_age){}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _os, const Student& _student);

private:
    std::string m_name;
    size_t m_age;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _os, const Student& _student)
{
    _os <<"Student " << _student.m_name << ", age: " << _student.m_age << std::endl;
    return _os;
}
```

And this is the cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"



int main()
{
    Student s1("Anna", 13);
    std::cout << s1;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a linkage error:
undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned int)'
(it's much longer, but I assume all has to do with the overloading of operator<<)

What am I doing wrong?

The full error:

```
/tmp/ccv0Mh7n.o: In function `operator<<(std::ostream&, Student const&)':
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned int)'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccv0Mh7n.o: In function `main':
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `std::cout'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/tmp/ccv0Mh7n.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
oplefshift.cpp:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccv0Mh7n.o: In function `Student::Student(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned int)':
oplefshift.cpp:(.text._ZN7StudentC2ENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEj[_ZN7StudentC5ENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEj]+0x11): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/ccv0Mh7n.o: In function `Student::~Student()':
oplefshift.cpp:(.text._ZN7StudentD2Ev[_ZN7StudentD5Ev]+0xe): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/ccv0Mh7n.o:(.eh_frame+0x93): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you `#include <iostream>` in your `.h` file?

Comment: The error is probably at the compil command line, or your project configuration if you use an ide.

Comment: @super I did inckude iostream. I compile with gcc in the terminal (linux)

Comment: Include the full error message in the question, please. (At least the relevant part)

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* C++ files should be compiled with `g++` command instead of `gcc`.

Comment: @S.M ahhh, thanks. So sorry for such a fullish mistake..

Comment: [Your code compiles with no errors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IreA0Ksf7l9wPrE4)

Comment: Also note that a function / operator definition shouldn't really be in a header file unless declared inline.

Answer (score 0):

Use `g++` to compile your code. If you are using `gcc`, add the `-lsdtc++` at the end.

`g++ student.cpp`

or

`gcc student.cpp -lstdc++`